# LilyPond - change tuplet bracket to a small bow

Tags: sheet-music, lilypond, engraving

I have a Cello piece from [Sebastian Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sebastian_Lee), that uses quite a lot of tuplets.

My snippet with the `default` [LilyPond](https://www.lilypond.org) setting looks like this:

[image]

this looks pretty nice, the problem is that a beginner could easaly think this was the fingering, especially in this example where as the `b` would be actually played with a third finger on the G string.

So I used `\override TupletBracket.bracket-visibility = ##t` to print the tuplet spanner/bracket that results in a very ugly print:

[image]

One edition, that is [available on IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/40_Easy_Etudes_for_Cello,_Op.70_(Lee,_Sebastian)) looks like this:

[image]

which I personally find somewhat nicer (not to be misunderstood, I'm only talking about the tuplet spanner, not about the whole print)

Does anyone on here know for a possible tweak of the spanner, to make it rather look like this small bow in the third example?

[Sebastian Lee, Op.70 in LilyPond format on GitHub](https://github.com/nathanaelmeister/Lee-_Sebastian_-_Op.70_-_40_Easy_Etudes_for_Cello)

Comment: See: http://lilypond.1069038.n5.nabble.com/Tuplets-curved-brackets-td207326.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A first approach would be to change the text of the tuplet number and append a small slur:

```
bow-up = \markup { \with-dimensions #'(0 . 3) #'(0 . 0) 
    \override #'(filled . #t) 
    \path #.1 #'((moveto 0 0)
                 (curveto 1 1.2 2 1.2 3 0)
                 (curveto 2 0.9 1 0.9 0 0)
                 (closepath)) }

bow-down = \markup { \with-dimensions #'(0 . 3) #'(0 . 0) 
    \override #'(filled . #t) 
    \path #.1 #'((moveto 0 0)
                 (curveto 1 -1.2 2 -1.2 3 0)
                 (curveto 2 -0.9 1 -0.9 0 0)
                 (closepath)) }

#(define-markup-command (tuplet-bow-up layout props tuplet-number) (markup?)
  (interpret-markup layout props
    (markup #:center-column(#:vspace -.2 bow-up #:vspace -.6 #:line(tuplet-number)))))

#(define-markup-command (tuplet-bow-down layout props tuplet-number) (markup?)
  (interpret-markup layout props
    (markup #:center-column(#:vspace .2 tuplet-number #:vspace -1 #:line(bow-down)))))

tupletBowUp = #(define-scheme-function (parser location tuplet-number) (string?)
     #{\override TupletNumber.text = \markup \tuplet-bow-up #tuplet-number #})

tupletBowDown = #(define-scheme-function (parser location tuplet-number) (string?)
     #{\override TupletNumber.text = \markup \tuplet-bow-down #tuplet-number #})

\score {
  { 
    \clef bass
    \time 3/4
    \tupletBowUp "3" \tuplet 3/2 { c8 b, c } \tupletBowDown "3" \tuplet 3/2 { e8 g e } \tuplet 3/2 { e8 g e } c'4
  }

  \layout{}
}
```

With `\tupletBowUp "3"` you set the number of all following tuplets to a 3 with a small bow above. With `\tupletBowDown "3"` you set it to a 3 with a small bow below. You can put other numbers as you like.

Result:

[image]

But I am sure, this can also be achieved in a much more sophisticated manner. However, I don’t know the internals of LilyPond that well. For example, it would be great to have the small bow automatically switch above or below the number according to its position.

---

**Edit:** Another way would be to change the tuplet bracket like [this proposal](https://archiv.lilypondforum.de/index.php/topic,1658.msg9226.html#msg9226) and [one comment](http://lilypond.1069038.n5.nabble.com/Tuplets-curved-brackets-td207326.html) suggest (sorry, I only saw the comment after having edited my answer). I changed the code from the linked proposal a bit to simplify it and to make the slurs smaller:

```
printTupletBow = {
  \override TupletBracket #'stencil = #ly:slur::print

  \override TupletBracket #'thickness = #1.2

  \override TupletBracket #'control-points =
    #(lambda (grob)
      (let* ((x-pos (ly:grob-property grob 'X-positions))
             (pos (ly:grob-property grob 'positions))
             (x-ln (interval-length x-pos))
             (dir (ly:grob-property grob 'direction))
             (height (- (cdr pos) (car pos)))
             (height-corr (* 0.3 dir height))
             (edge-height (ly:grob-property grob 'edge-height '(0.7 . 0.7))))

        (list 
          (cons 
            (+ (car x-pos) (* x-ln 1/4)) 
            (+ (car pos) (* 1 dir (car edge-height))))
          (cons 
            (+ (car x-pos) (* x-ln 3/8)) 
            (+ (car pos) (* dir (+ 1.5 height-corr))))
          (cons 
            (+ (car x-pos) (* x-ln 5/8)) 
            (+ (cdr pos) (* dir (- 1.5 height-corr))))
          (cons 
            (+ (car x-pos) (* x-ln 3/4))  
            (+ (cdr pos) (* 1 dir (cdr edge-height)))))))
}

\score {
  {
    \clef bass
    \time 3/4
    \tuplet 3/2 { c8 b, c } \tuplet 3/2 { e8 g e } \tuplet 3/2 { e8 g e } c'4
  }
}

\layout {
  \printTupletBow
}
```

Result:

[image]

If you want to temporarily omit the bows, you can use `\once \override TupletBracket.stencil = ##f` just before the relevant tuplet.

One problem with this approach is that the slur will be slanted quite a lot if the notes span bigger intervals. But it might be a nice solution if your piece includes mainly tuplets with beams.

Comment: I'll post your link in [LilyPonds official IRC on Freenode](https://webchat.freenode.net/#lilypond), maybe they are inspired... :-) as I am! (ot looks so much nicer then the bracket!)

Comment: No need to do that, because I also took inspiration from there. So, the basic code may already be there as well.

Comment: is there a way to omit the bows further on in the piece, as you do with `\omit TupletNumber`?

Comment: For the second example, you can use `\once \override TupletBracket.stencil = ##f`.

Comment: you should definitely add this to the [LSR - Snippet Repository](http://lsr.di.unimi.it/)