# Lilypond - Moving around the number for a tuplet

Tags: lilypond, engraving, tuplet

I'm trying to replicate a triplet drawn as a bow with the number over the bow rather than under and shifted to hover over the first note.  By following [LilyPond - change tuplet bracket to a small bow](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/92506/lilypond-change-tuplet-bracket-to-a-small-bow), I got the bow/slur.  Now, how do I move the number?

I want the number and bow to be positioned like this:

[image]

So far I have this code

```
\tupletUp \tuplet 3/2 {a16[A16 f16]}
```

to get this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how to the the "3" outside of the bracket/slur (or why you'd want that), but in the newer versions of LilyPond there is an inbuilt method to get slurs for tuplet brackets, `\override TupletBracket.tuplet-slur = ##t` (see: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/writing-rhythms#tuplets).

Comment: I've already figured out that override to get slurs for tuple brackets.  The reason I want the numbers is that I have a lot of sheet music done like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you’d move the Tuplet Number simply by offsetting its X/Y-offset values. If you want some refinement maybe do

```
{
  \override TupletNumber.Y-offset =
  #(lambda (grob)
     (let* ((bracket (ly:grob-object grob 'bracket))
            (stc (ly:grob-property grob 'stencil))
            (ext (ly:stencil-extent stc Y))
            (align (ly:grob-property grob 'self-alignment-Y 0))
            (palign (ly:grob-property grob 'parent-alignment-Y align))
            (align (/ (1+ align) 2))
            (palign (/ (1+ palign) 2))
            (pos (ly:grob-property bracket 'positions)))
       (+ (* palign (cdr pos)) (* (- 1 palign) (car pos))
          (* align (cdr ext)) (* (- 1 palign) (car ext)))))
  \override TupletNumber.X-offset =
  #(lambda (grob)
     (let* ((bracket (ly:grob-object grob 'bracket))
            (stc (ly:grob-property grob 'stencil))
            (ext (ly:stencil-extent stc X))
            (align (ly:grob-property grob 'self-alignment-X 0))
            (palign (ly:grob-property grob 'parent-alignment-X align))
            (align (/ (1+ align) 2))
            (palign (/ (1+ palign) 2))
            (pos (ly:grob-property bracket 'X-positions)))
       (display palign)
       (+ (* palign (cdr pos)) (* (- 1 palign) (car pos))
          (* align (cdr ext)) (* (- 1 palign) (car ext)))))

  \override TupletBracket.tuplet-slur = ##t
  \override TupletNumber.padding =
  #(lambda (grob)
     (let ((b (ly:grob-object grob 'bracket)))
       (- (interval-center (ly:grob-property b 'edge-height)))))
  \override TupletNumber.self-alignment-Y =
  #(lambda (grob)
     (ly:grob-property (ly:grob-object grob 'bracket) 'direction))
  \override TupletNumber.parent-alignment-Y =
  #(lambda (grob)
     (* 2 (ly:grob-property (ly:grob-object grob 'bracket) 'direction)))
  \override TupletNumber.parent-alignment-X = #-0.8

  \tuplet 3/2 { c'4 d' e' }
  \tuplet 3/2 { c''4 d'' e'' }
}
```

This would look like this

[image]